# Логика регистрации пользователя (что делать если пользователь с таким именем существует)

Tags: java, servlet

Проект на Spring Security. В базе есть уникальный столбец по имени. Если регистрируется новый пользователь под существующим ником,то получаем:

> whitelabel eror.

Что логично. Хочу спросить, где правильней всего сделать проверку на существование поля Логин? В сервлете, когда создаем нового пользователя? Или может скрипт со страницы сам должен идти в базу MySQL и сверяться, когда пользователь печатает логин?

Comment: Можно сделать и скриптом и в сервлете, но при создании нового пользователя проверка должна быть обязательной (либо обрабатываем `exception` существования логина).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Естественно сервлетом -

```
User user = userService.findUserByName(username);
if (user == null {
    model.addAttribute("error", "Can't find username. Check login/password");
}
```

Comment: CustomPerson customPerson = personService.getPersonByLogin(login);
        if (customPerson != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "this login is used");